# pg-promise inserting text with $()

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I'm having trouble inserting text into my database when the text contains the string "$(...)" 
as my code return the Error: Property '...' doesn't exist.

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({ promiseLib: bluebird });
const db = pgp(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
let values = [{text: 'this is fine'}, {text: 'this fails $(...)'}];
let cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['text']);
let query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs);
db.manyOrNone(query);
```

Is there some sort of "this is just text" property I'm missing?

Thanks

EDIT
Error was only occurring when using $() syntax to add other variables to the whole SQL call

```
'use strict';
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({ promiseLib: bluebird });
const db = pgp('postgres://localhost/okeydokey-local');

db.any(
  'CREATE TABLE text_table ( ' +
    'text_column text ' +
  ')'
);
let values = [{ text_column: 'this is fine' }, { text_column: 'this fails $(test)' }];
let cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['text_column'], {table: 'text_table'});
let query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs);
console.log(query);
db.manyOrNone(query +
  'some more SQL dependent on $(somethingElse)',
  {
    somethingElse: 'someValue'
  }
);
```

Output

```
insert into "text_table"("text_column") values('this is fine'),('this fails $(test)')
Unhandled rejection Error: Property 'test' doesn't exist.
```

Comment: Please be more specific which line/operation is failing for you exactly. Also please provide the query generated, and full code (the one in your example cannot work, because you do not specify any table when generating a query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line generates your final query:

```
let query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs);
//=>insert into "text_table"("text_column") values('this is fine'),('this fails $(test)')
```

It is not a query template for further formatting, it is supposed to be executed directly.

In your code you are trying to format the final query string, which breaks trying to locate property `test` in your formatting object.

Comment: Is it possible to use a helper to produce an insert query such as 
'insert into "text_table"("text_column") values('this is fine'),('this fails $(test)')
on conflict do update set ...

As I wish to do a similar thing as this where currently my update statement inputs variables using $(variable)

Comment: @Nathsn Evant, just append your  'ON CONFLICT' part to the generated query string.

Comment: @NathanEvans if for some reasons you want to amend a string that requires formatting, you should generate it separately, like through `pgp.as.format()`, for example. You should NOT try to inject variables into the generated final query, because it already may contain strings that look like variables, there is no way of knowing what it may have as string values.